# Matrix have infinitely or unique solution?

Tags: linear-algebra

My HW problem is below. Does the matrix count as having 3 or 4 variables? The 3rd column has no 1 in it, but does that mean it still has a variable there? 
The matrix is

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0&|&-3\\0&1&0&0&|&-2\\0&0&0&1&|&-1\\0&0&0&0&|&0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: There are $4$ variables, say $x,y,z,t.$ We get $x=-3,y=-2,z=?,t=-1.$ So, $z=0,z=1$ are solutions. Can you get more solutions?

Comment: Hmm. How did you get z = 0, z = 1?

Comment: There is no condition on $z.$ Thus $z$ can be any real number.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions, instead of posting an image.

Comment: Oh okay thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not familiar with solving equation systems in matrix form, you should write them as "whole" equations. If you do that for some time, you will see that they are the same - just written differently.

\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0&|&-3\\0&1&0&0&|&-2\\0&0&0&1&|&-1\\0&0&0&0&|&0\end{pmatrix}

is equivalent to: 
\begin{matrix}1x_1&+&0x_2&+&0x_3&+&0x_4&=&-3\\0x_1&+&1x_2&+&0x_3&+&0x_4&=&-2\\0x_1&+&0x_2&+&0x_3&+&1x_4&=&-1\\0x_1&+&0x_2&+&0x_3&+&0x_4&=&0\end{matrix}

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say that the matrix is augmented matrix $(A|B) $ we can clearly see that $r (A)=r (B) $ but $r (A)=r (B)< \text {number of variables=4} $ hence there exist infinite solutions.

Answer (score 0):

A *matrix* doesn't have variables. But what you're imagining — some system of equations described by that matrix — does have four variables.

What you're having trouble with here is that notation is ambiguous.

Normally if I asked you to solve the equation $x=3$, you read the equations and infer that the question means to ask for solutions in $x$, and there would only be one solution.

However, I could ask you for solutions to $x=3$ in $x$ and $y$, and there are infinitely many! There is only one way to assign a value to $x$, of course, but you can assign anything to $y$.

So, your trouble is that you're imagining some system of equations corresponding to this matrix (and implicitly simplifying by skipping over the terms corresponding to the zero entries), the resulting equation only has three 'visible' variables, and then your training to fill in the implicit information is urging you to think that the question is asking about solutions just in those three variables.

However, four variables are intended; this is clear from the way the problem is presented to you, with the array of coefficients having four columns.

It may help to think of this not as an equation of scalar variables, but as an equation involving a single *vector* variable: the problem is to find the solutions to

$$ 
\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}
\mathbf{x} = 
\begin{pmatrix}-3 \\ -2 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$